# Time series Analysis with Non Numerical data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, categorical-data

I have a data over the 1 hour interval time stamp with 20 varible columns (sensor data), but it doesnt has any crisp value like 220.4 all the values are like signal strength Eg:" Good" or "bad" or "invalid" . I would like to identify pattern over the time it has occured. As I am new to the analytics , kindly help me how can i proceed .

Comment: please provide more information such as what kind of pattern you want to identify and what you consider a pattern (seasonal changes?, change in relation to a specific variable?, interdependence between two variables?) While you do not provide such information, I can only recommend encoding your strings numerically such as invalid - 0, bad-1, good-2 which enables you to use more methods (not only string based methods)

Answer (score 0):

You could transform each "good", "bad", "invalid" or other state as a 1 or 0 (True or False) per time, for each time series, similar to:

```
time v1_g v1_b v1_i v2_g v2_b v2_i
1    0    1    0    1    0    0
2    1    0    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    1    0    0    1
4    0    0    1    1    0    0
5    0    1    0    1    0    0
6    1    0    0    0    1    0
7    0    1    0    1    0    0
8    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

Where time=1, v1_b=1 indicates that at time=1 variable #1 is "bad", etc.

Then you can use a Pearson cross correlation to compare your variables, e.g. the correlation between the columns v1_g and v2_g = -0.8, the correlation between the columns v1_b and v2_b = -0.6